# Creating polygon via a PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis

I am totally new to PyQGIS.

On my computer I have QGIS 3.X installed, from what I understand, Python 3 can already be used to use PyQGIS.

It is my need to create a script to georeference a polygon already having the 4 vertices, in a WGS84 reference system with UTM projection, Zone 19S:

For reference, the points are the following:

P1
X = 327648
y = 6312423

P2
X = 359516
Y = 6315323

P3
X = 324401
Y = 6278368

P4
X = 363486
Y = 6269735

Later, I need to export those vertices as points or as vertices.

Any guidance?

Comment: Look like you want to create a polygon out of four points, is not it?

Comment: "Georeferencing" is the process of assigning ground coordinates to raster data without them.  You can't georeference vector coordinates in a known coordinate system.  Even "export" seems the wrong goal. Please [Edit] the Question to tell a story about what you are trying to accomplish, possibly with pictures, and without unfamiliar technical terms.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to create a polygon geometry from it, on a layer with a specified CRS, so that it aligns with other geodata, then this would be a literal approach:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:32719', 'MyLayer', 'memory')

points = [
    QgsPoint(x=327648, y=6312423),
    QgsPoint(x=359516, y=6315323),
    QgsPoint(x=324401, y=6278368),
    QgsPoint(x=363486, y=6269735),
]
exterior_ring = QgsLineString(points)
polygon = QgsPolygon(exterior_ring)

feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(polygon)

with edit(layer):
    layer.addFeature(feature)

layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Be aware that the order of your points results in an invalid "hour-glass" geometry though:

[image]